# tf/tutorials/adding a frame

Tags: turtlesim, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After I run the problem, all I can see and do is to move turtle1 turtle2 is always stationary no matter where I moved my turtle1. Is there anything I miss doing ? I am running in groovy.
Thank you
Edwin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/133851/tf/tutorials/adding-a-frame/) by [elthef](https://answers.ros.org/users/9256/elthef/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2014-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok I have solve the problem...

---

Originally posted by [elthef](https://answers.ros.org/users/9256/elthef/) with karma: 26 on 2014-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0